# Read and load external config xml file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net site. I need to use external config file abc.xml for the configuration instead of the web.config file. How can I implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config, inside your `<configuration>` tag, try to use `<appSettings file="path_to_your_file\abc.config" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it from your code behind file

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Root");
```

[Have the look on this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/working-with-more-then-one-web-config-files-in-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

Save a path to your config file in web.config. Access the file from the path and get what you need from it.